# passing index of link clicked from jsp to popup using jquery

Tags: jquery, struts2

I have jsp with list of Amazon "orders" displayed and "order#" as link. When I clicked on link I wanted to display more details in popup.

My question is how do I get the details in popup jsp for the selected link without going to database again using the same list from parent page.

I am using `<s:subset source="devOrdLst" count="1" start="">` I am assuming if I get the start value that is nothing but index then I can display details of that clicked order#.

Technologies used jQuery, Struts2, java. Please don't suggest any plugins.

Parent Page:

```
<s:iterator value="orderList" id="orders">
   <tr>
      <td><a href="#" id=orderid><s:property value="orderId"/></a></td>
      <td><s:property value="orderDate"/></td>
      <td><s:property value="CustomerName"/></td>
   </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

In popup based on selected orderId I have display the details from **orderList** by index **without hitting server.**

How do I pass this from parent window to popup using jQuery.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you have a link, pass a url parameter.

Comment: I have added some more details, hoping you understand now.

Answer (score 0):

it should look like this:

```
<s:iterator value="orderList" status="status">
   <tr>
      <td>
          <%-- action maybe a jsp page or java class --%>
          <s:url var="url" action="detail">
            <s:param name="index" value="#status.index"/>
            <s:param name="orderId" value="%{orderId}"/>
          <a href="%{url}">
            <s:property value="orderId"/>
          </a>
      </td>
      <td><s:property value="orderDate"/></td>
      <td><s:property value="CustomerName"/></td>
   </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

so you can pass your orderId and index...

**UPDATE 1**

If you really do not wanna call the server again. you can try this out. i do not have environment here, so you have to do it by yourself.

```
<s:iterator value="orderList" status="status">
   <tr id="<s:property value="%{orderId}">">
      <td>
          <%-- action maybe a jsp page or java class --%>
          <a href="#" id="orderId">
            <s:property value="orderId"/>
          </a>
      </td>
      <td><s:property value="orderDate"/></td>
      <td><s:property value="CustomerName"/></td>
   </tr>
</s:iterator>
<div id="popup"></div>
<script>
  $("a#orderId").click(function(){
    var orderId = this.val();
    var result= "<ul>";
    $('tr[id=orderId] td').each(function(){
        result.append("<li>" + this.html() + "</li>");
    });
    result.append("</ul>");
    $('#popup').html(result);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I don't want to hit the server again, within jquery or javascript I can pull that only record from that list?

Comment: <s:subset/> is server script, how could you interpret struts tag into html without communicating with server? you can sure print all the information and hide them, then show them using jquery selector. you have to offer the interpreted html code first...

Comment: @Bala check out UPDATE 1. it may help you